# How to check how many pages are using a certain skin in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am sitting with a situation where I need to check how many pages in my site are using a specific skin. In Sitefinity, you can check which pages are using a certain template and I wanted to know if this is possible in DNN please?

Thanks, 
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to your database, this code will get you all pages in DNN that override the default skin with the `store_limited` skin.

```
select TabID, TabName, TabPath from tabs where SkinSrc like '%store_limited%'
```

Confirmed working in 5.6.0

**To run this code from within DNN**

1. Login as Host
2. Go to Hosts menu
3. Click on SQL
4. Select your DNN connection string
5. Paste in the above code
6. Press execute

Comment: Thanks hamlin11. I was hoping for an easier route than this before diving into the SQL pool, but ok then ;) thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to execute this code from within DotNetNuke to provide you the list that you need.